# connect custom list to outlook

Tags: list, outlook

I created a SharePoint custom list and now I want to connect this list to Outlook.

How is it possible to do this?

P.S. From task list or document library I am successful in attaching the list to Outlook.
I do this by:
document list-->Action-->connect to outlook.

Answer (score 1):

From my research I found that By default the custom lists cannot connect to outlook. All the fields required for the outlook are not present in outlook.

You can try this tool - [stssyncprovider](http://stssyncprovider.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

It MIGHT be pretty easy:

Try to use the task list and then delete columns and views you dont need. You basicly strip that task list down to a pseudo-custom list. Worked for me the last time, but you might have other requirements we dont know about.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you wanna do this? If you need your list content offline, you might take a look at SharePoint Workspace. If you need the information in your Inbox, you could either subscribe to the list's RSS-feed or configure E-Mail notifications for that list to be sent whenever list content changes.